Karate desktop automation - application launch issue and locators difference between Windows and Mac OS


Unable to launch the application for Mac OS using the below Karate-robot fork option



robot {fork: '/WindowsApps/ABCD.apk'}

Meanwhile same application path is working fine in windows with karate-robot-fork option.
Desktop application elements which is identified in Windows are not recognized in Mac OS.
For launching the application instead of using Karate Robot fork option I have used external Java class and call the function.
I am also able to launch the application in Mac by calling the external java class.
Expectation: need a help to launch the application in mac via Robot fork command.
For Object identification issue, I have used the external Java function to recognize the objects as below
def `appleScriptHelper `= Java.type('utils.AppleScriptHelper')

# Open the application
* appleScriptHelper.openApplication(appPath)

# Click the login button
* appleScriptHelper.clickLoginButton()\


this is a case where I think your best approach is to contribute code, and I think you should try your best to convince your team / org to invest time into this

fyi there is no programming question here, and honestly, the way this question is formatted, it's hard to read what you did post). Please read [ask] and how to provide a [mcve]. All that aside: it's not clear that this question is for Stack Overflow, vs as an issue to something you're attempting to work with.
